# How do I pass arguments to a Glue job in CloudFormation YAML?

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue

You can pass arguments to an AWS Glue job via the `--arguments` parameter (see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-glue-arguments.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-python-intro-parameters)).

The [CloudFormation documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-glue-job.html#cfn-glue-job-defaultarguments) says DefaultArguments are "UTF-8 string–to–UTF-8 string key-value pairs" and that their type is "JSON object". Since YAML is a super set of JSON, I was expecting to be able to pass arguments like this in a (YAML) CloudFormation template:

```
DefaultArguments:
  "--arguments": {"--test_argument": "foo"}
```

However, it raises this error during CloudFormation deployment:

> Property validation failure: [Value of property {/DefaultArguments/--arguments=} does not match type {String}]

How do I specify the values correctly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct way of passing multiple parameters is

```
DefaultArguments:
  "--argument1": value1
  "--argument2": value2
```

and then accessing them in the job (e.g. in Python) like this:

```
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['argument1', 'argument2'])
print args['argument1']
print args['argument2']
```

What confused me was that for passing parameters with the AWS CLI, you use an explicit `--arguments='--argument1="value1"'` structure but in CloudFormation, you specify arguments one by one.

Comment: I was missing the `--`. No need for quotes though.

Answer (score 1):

The value for the key `--arguments` needs to be a string, but you actually give it a mapping (or in JSON-speak an object), because it starts witha `{`. You should quote the value, and since you have double quotes in the value, you best do that with single quotes:

```
DefaultArguments:
  "--arguments": '{"--test_argument": "foo"}'
```

(any existing single quotes in the value you would need to escape by putting two single quotes)

If your JSON is more complex it can be benificial to use folded-style scalars. Within those the `{` has no special meaning either and (single) newlines followed by spaces are replaced by a single space. So the following loads to same data as the solution above:

```
DefaultArguments:
  "--arguments": >
    {"--test_argument": 
        "foo"}
```

Of course with YAML (1.2) being a superset of JSON, `glue` could easily assume  that a value is already parsed if it is not a string, but it doesn't seem to be that smart and always expects the JSON in string form.

Comment: When I pass arguments as `'{"--test_argument": "foo"}'`, CloudFormation passes them on to Glue as  `{"--arg1"="arg1", "--arg2"="arg2"}` which then fails because Glue's `getResolvedOptions` uses `argparse` which doesn't understand JSON input, and I get `awsglue.utils.GlueArgumentError: argument --arg1 is required`.

Comment: That is definately not a JSON object definition then that they expect in the scalar, but just a (JSON) string. You should probably just provide it like you would on the commandline.

Comment: That's what I thought. When I do `'--arg1="arg1" --arg2="arg2"'`, Glue doesn't find `arg2`. Sounds like a bug. I've cut a ticket with AWS support.

Comment: Could it be that they expect a JSON list in string that is a value for key `--arguments`? Like `'["--arg1", "arg1", "--arg2", "arg2"]'`?